# AWS CloudFormation use existing security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to use existing security group on cloudformation template.
Now I have template that create 2 SG,

```
 "InstanceMember1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "privateSubnetA"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
          {
            "Ref": "MongoSg"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "mongoTrafficSG"
          } 
        ],
    }
}

"MongoSg": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "MongoDB security group",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "22",
            "ToPort": "22",
            "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
              "Ref": "bastionSG"
            }
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": "%%vpc-id%%",
      }
}
}
```

Now I want to add to the instance exist security group id, any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can just go ahead and specify the security group name:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroups

```
 "InstanceMember1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "privateSubnetA"
        },
        "SecurityGroups": [ "mysuperawesomealreadyexistinggroup"],
    }
}
```

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the SecurityGroup can also be passed in as a parameter, and can also be created in the same CloudFormation template as the security groups.  There are several ways to handle this.

Comment: No longer possible w/ VPC.

Comment: I always find hard to orient in the vast of cloudformation components documentation. Here is the link to docs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroups

Comment: This solution is for EC2 classic only. The instance is in VPC (referencing a subnet), so this solution will not work in VPC.

Comment: Can still be done the same way in VPC as well: just replace `SecurityGroups` with `SecurityGroupId` and provide one or more security group IDs in the array. But Only Security Group Ids work in this case, not group names.